# Text filled by balls

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, text-object

i am new to Blender , and in C4D ,i know it is very convenient to use motion graph to generate such kind of effect , Besides it is very convenient to adjust text content , and i discover Blender for a while and google stuffs , but there seems no relative tutorials .

some similar methods are feasible ,but you cant change text content anymore after you convert it to mesh!

Any one know specific or probable solutions or tutorials?

[image]

Comment: there are tons of very tutorials on youtube https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+tutorial , for example Blender Guru has many good tuts for beginners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If no one ... classic

- add Text convert to Mesh
- add Balls, set in Collection, add Physics > Riggid Body > Active
- add Particle system > Source from Volume, Render > Collection
- enable addon **[Copy Particles to Riggid Bodies](https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-particles-to-rigid-bodies/563269)**, run operator (take some time)
- disable particle system for Text (Mesh) object and add Physics > Riggid Body > Passive

To change letters - type a new text, convert to mesh, assign Particle system, run addon, set Riggid Body.

I know almost the same, but still just a few clicks now, that you would have to in C4D as well (if I checked tut right).

[image]

**Note:** Particles were quite jumping out (because I did them too big), so I did a duplication of Text mesh and inset the shape, so they are generated from object inside collision Text mesh.

[image]
[image]

(Naming of the addon could be improved cross UI, but awesome it exists and **still working in 3.4** even written for 2.8 :))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice! you should share the blend file. that can be helpful for the OP.

Comment: I can't find this add on "Copy Particles to Rigid Bodies" in blender. Could you please let me know where can I find it or anything similar? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @sahil The first thread found by google ...[addon for 2.8 still works for 3.4](https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-particles-to-rigid-bodies/563269) ... don't forget to enable RB for balls used as instances in particle system before you run the operator.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do that also. You don't even need the add-on.

[image]

[image]

- Run the particle simulation for a short while (space)
- Convert it to objects

[image]

- Go to Object > Rigid Body > Add Active
- Shift-select one ball
- Go to the Rigid Body tab and put shape to Sphere
- Right-click it and 'Copy to Selected' to put it to all selected spheres
- Continue playing (space), let the balls settle
- Stop the simulation
- Select one ball > Shift+G > Collection
- Object > Rigid Body > Apply Transformation
- Scrub the timeline so nothing is moving anymore
- Remove the overflown balls by hand

Comment: Ha ... nice :) I used addon for two reasons - create "filling" animation and also don't let particles explode when becomes riggid because they'r initially intersects. Your way has a big advantage - work with much more particles with less computations. Congrats. BTW would be good to mention Gravity OFF and Velocity is probably not needed. Apply Transformation just get current position as default and has to be used several times. If you wan to stop anim isnt it better Bake to Keyframes (start on last) so Riggid is applied. Or you wanted to keep Riggid active?